# Apache Camel: Ignore "Circular error-handler detected at route" warning

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a route in Apache Camel which creates a message with asset IDs and sends it off to an end-point expecting a response with information on the assets.

Sometimes the end-point may respond that one of the assets isn't accepted, and so my route will create a new message and send back to the end-point. The end-point is only capable of responding with one unaccepted asset per request, so the second request to the end point may result in another response indicating an asset hasn't been accepted.

```
from("my-route")
    .routeId("my-route-id")
    // my-route accepts the message that will be sent to the end point
    .to(endpoint)
    .onException(SpecificFault.class)
        // processor creates a new message, with the invalid asset retrieved from the SpecificFault Exceptionremoved
        .process(invalidAssetProcessor)
    .end()
    .to("destination")
.end();
```

The code runs fine and processed as expected; when one invalid asset is returned a new message is sent with that invalid asset removed.

When there is a second invalid asset I'm getting the following error:

> "Circular error-handler detected at route: my-route-id - breaking out
> processing Exchange:
> Exchange[2D95F3E2F212B18-0000000000000001]","logger_name":"org.apache.camel.processor.FatalFallbackErrorHandler","thread_name":"Camel
> (camel-1) thread #3 -
> timer://simpleTimer","level":"WARN","level_value":30000}
>
> "Exception occurred while trying to handle previously thrown exception
> on exchangeId: 2D95F3E2F212B18-0000000000000001 using: [null]. The
> previous and the new exception will be logged in the
> following.","logger_name":"org.apache.camel.processor.FatalFallbackErrorHandler","thread_name":"Camel
> (camel-1) thread #3 -
> timer://simpleTimer","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000}

It seems that underlying code thinks that encountering the same Exception twice could lead to an infinite loop and stops. Is there a way for me to disable this safety mechanism for this Exception route?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using a try catch block within Camel:

```
from("my-route")
    .routeId("my-route-id")
    .try()
        .to(endpoint)
    .doCatch(SpecificFault.class)
        .process(invalidAssetProcessor)
    .end()
    .to("destination")
.end();
```